# running a nodejs express project from c# windows application

Tags: c#, node.js, winforms

Is there a way to run an express nodejs project from a c# windows application?
i have the following project

Is there a way to run `server.js` in `ServerCode` project on the startup of the windows application?
i found this link: https://gist.github.com/elerch/5628117 talking about using: `System.Diagnostics.Process` but i didn't know how to use it and i couldn't find any article talking about the same issue as mine

i don't want to go to the server project and run `npm start` or `node server.js`
i want to do these commands from c# itself is it possible?

[image]

Comment: There are plenty of examples of using process around the internet. Try to find one and return when you have a concrete question regarding the code.

Comment: that's what i am doing but i can't find any clear answer for my problem

Comment: It seems that you develop an Outlook plugin. Have you written/tried any code inside the c# project? Have you any experience with sharp? The gist you have posted is quite easy to adapt to your case. Change the `FileName` to *npm* and `Arguments` to *start* remove lines 24 and 25 and try.

Answer (score -1):

I Already find a way to execute the behavior that i want hence for future reference if anyone has a similar problem this is what i have done

Using a library called [pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg) i was able to create an exe file for my server and then by c# i called the exe as followed

```
 public static void LanchNodeJsServer()
    {
        try
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = ThisAddIn.ServerFolder;
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "node-js-server-win.exe";
            p.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CLogger.WriteLog(ELogLevel.ERROR, "Helpers  --> LanchNodeJsServer : error:" + ex);
        }
    }
```